# Angular 4 - Custom two way binding

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a custom two way binding between two of my components.

I did read about the naming convention saying that you have to define a `@Input()` like "`test`" and then define a `@Output()` named "`testChange`".

I couldn't find anything about whether this is still up-to-date or not and I can't get my binding to work.

Some code within parentComponent:

`<my-comp [(userGroupIds)]="userGroups"></my-comp>`

MyComponent (child):

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  @Input() userGroupIds: number[];
  @Output() userGroupIdsChange = new EventEmitter<number[]>();

  updateValues(){
    //here I am iterating through the rows of a table within my component
    this.userGroupIds = this.tableRows.map(item => {return item['id']});
    this.userGroupdIdsChange.emit(this.userGroupIds);
  }
}
```

parentComponent:

```js
export class parentComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestry{
  userGroups: number[];
  constructor(){
    this.userGroups = [];
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    if(changes['userGroups']){
      // this is never show, ngOnChanges doesn't get fired;
      console.log(this.userGroups);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something I am missing? Did the Angular-Team change anything?

Afaik the binding does something like

```html
[userGroupsIds]="userGroups" (userGroupsIdsChange)="userGroupIds=$event"
```

So I tried setting this myself, but no update either. Only thing that work was passing a function to the eventEmitter.

Comment: `ngOnChanges` only fires if any of `@Input`'s has changed. I don't see any `@Input`'s in your parent component. And change should come from parent component(parent of your parentComponent)

Comment: You have a typo - extra `d` in `userGroupdIdsChange`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your binding works like a charm, it does not trigger the `ngOnchanges` method, which is the expected behavior.

from the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) :

> ## OnChanges
>
> Lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes.

as `userGroups` is not an `@Input()` it cannot be a "data-bound property" , its value changing internally will not run the `ngOnChanges` hook.

Comment: Oh dear, I really feel stupid right now. I wasn't even close on thinking about ngOnChanges being the "problem" here. Thank you! Works like a charm indeed. edit: Is there something other that would do what I  expected OnChanges to do?